# The value of the field 'nameOfField' is not used - Java Swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, warnings, compiler-warnings

I got some `JButton`'s ,`JLabel` and `JTextField` in a `class`.
I Simply initialize them in panel.add() method and i got near each one of them a `The value of the field 'nameOfField' is not used` warning.

My class:

```
public class GuiClass 
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPanel upperPanel;
    private JPanel lowerPanel;

    public GuiClass()
    {
        this.frame = new JFrame("Complex layout GUI example");
        this.upperPanel = new JPanel();
        this.lowerPanel = new JPanel();

        this.upperPanel.add(this.label = new JLabel("Enter your password:"));
        this.upperPanel.add(this.textField = new JTextField(20)); // Size of the textField
        this.lowerPanel.add(this.button1 = new JButton("Cancel"));
        this.lowerPanel.add(this.button2 = new JButton("Login"));

        this.frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        this.frame.add(this.upperPanel);
        this.frame.add(this.lowerPanel);

        this.frame.pack();
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The warning is near button1,button2,label and textField.
I'm using `Eclipse`. What bothers it?

**PS**

I can generate getter's and setter's and the warnings obviously gone but I want to learn from it about Java programming what is my mistake(If there is any).

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse see's there is no need for fields like `button2` since you're never actually using them. The add could be done without the assignment here so that's not a real usage. Introducing public getters gets rid of the warning since the field _could_ be accessed indirectly via that getter and Eclipse doesn't know whether this is the case or not (you could be writing a library etc.)

Comment: Other IDEs have a similar feature.

Comment: @Thomas Well , It's a faster way to write code like that. So.... Should i change it to first initialize the variables and then add or just leave it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's really faster and it for sure is less easy to read, especially when you start using more parameters in the `add()` calls (like layout constraints etc.). You could get rid of the fields if you don't ever access them but in the case of the buttons for example you'll probably access them to add some ActionListeners etc. which will get rid of the warning.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. I noticed if  i change the accessibility of the to `public` i don't get any warnings. If they are `public` they are used and if they are `private` they don't? Where is the logic here?

Comment: `public` fields _could_ be used by external callers while `private` can't be (except when applying reflection but with that you can do other nasty things as well that the compiler just won't warn you about). Thus the compiler/IDE will warn you if it knows _for sure_ (again reflection is ignored here) that no external caller can access that field. Note that `protected` and default visibility have the same effect as `public` here since an external source could add subclasses or extend the package.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks man. I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private JFrame frame;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JLabel label;               //All Fields are private 
private JTextField textField;
private JPanel upperPanel;
private JPanel lowerPanel;
```

> Here All `refrence` Variable that u made are `private`. It means all member variables have Scope of this `Class` Only. So, You Should use all of these `refrence variables` with in this Class. **Otherwise** `eclipse` will show a warning. However these warnings are not a error but Some smart `IDE` like `eclipse` and `Intelli j Idea` will warn you if any unused `variables` you have declared.

Now comes to the your second argument. Which is

> Generate getter's and setter's and the warnings obviously gone ?

If you generate `getters` and `setters`. These have `public` modifiers it means you may use these `variable` Outside of Class to `set` or `get` the values of member `variables` . So, It will not raise any `Warning` because `eclipse` sense that these member variables may use outside of `Class`.

Thank you.